# Assign a type to a selected portions

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to output a type as "int" if we select from say A1:A5, contains (1,2,3,4,5);
but output a type as "string" if we have (1,2,hello,4,5)

Answer (score 3):

Another variation

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:A5)<COUNTA(A1:A5),"string","int")
```

This compares the number of numbers in an array to the number of items in an array.

Comment: Nice method. It may be worth mentioning that text-that-looks-like-a-number (e.g. `"9"`) does not register with COUNT, only COUNTA.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=if(isnumber(--(a1&a2&a3&a4&a5)), "int", "string")
```

Comment: Nice approach. Or `= IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1:A5+0)),"int","string")`. This might need to be entered as array formula though.